# Complexity after Arrays.sort and for loop

Tags: java, big-o

In java, if I sort using `Arrays.sort()` (`n log n`) and then use a for loop o(n) in the code, what will be the new complexity ? is it `n^2 log n` or `n log n`

Comment: [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11032015). [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3255)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: **O(nLog(n))**

non nested complexities can be simply added. i.e. O(n) + O(nLog(n))

For large n, nLog(n) is significantly greater than n. Therefore, O(nLog(n)) is the answer.

Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

**Note:**

if the complexities are nested then the complexities are multiplied, for example:

Inside a loop of **order n**, you are doing a sort of **order nLog(n)**.

Then complexity will be **O(n * nLog(n))**. i.e. **O(n²Log(n))**

Answer (score 4):

If you perform the `for` loop **after**, you have an O(nlog(n)) operation followed by an O(n) one. Since O(n) is negligible compared to O(nlog(n)), your overall complexity would be O(nlog(n)).